# Can a line in a projective plane have just two points?

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, axioms

Here is the definition of a projective plane from Stillwell's *The Four Pillars of Geometry* (2005, Springer):

Let $\cal P$ ("points") be a set, and let $\cal L$ ("lines") be a set of subsets of $\cal P.$ We say $({\cal P},{\cal L})$ is a *projective plane* to mean

1. Any two distinct points lie on exactly one line;
2. Any two distinct lines intersect at exactly one point; and
3. There exist four points with the property that no three of these points are collinear.

Can a line have cardinality strictly less than 3? People sometimes add an axiom saying that

4. Every line has cardinality at least 3. (Cf. Beck-Bleicher-Crowe's *Excursions into Mathematics: The Millenium Edition* (2000, CRC Press).)

I was wondering whether this fourth axiom is implied by the first three axioms. It is not extremely difficult to [show](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4102197/279330) that lines must have at least two points. Thus, we can reformulate the question as: **Can a line have exactly two points?**

Comment: You have posted a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4102197) with 2 points instead of 1 just before. You should refer to it (or more exactly to the first issue where you have had an answer).

Comment: @JeanMarie I think you meant to post this comment on the other post...

Comment: Gossett's _Discrete Mathematics with Proof_ (2003, Pearson) affirms in Lemma 8.3 the conjectured result: that every line has cardinality at least 3. He proves the result by first showing the "dual" of Axiom 3:
**3'. There exist four lines with the property that no three of these lines have a common point.**

Answer (score 2):

No. Let $A, B, C, D$ be four points that axiom 3 guarantees. The line $AB$ must meet line $CD$ in a third point $E$ on each of those two lines.

It follows that every line must contain at least three points since all lines have the same number of points. To see that, suppose $L$ and $M$ are different lines. Pick some $P$ on neither. Then join $P$ to all the points on $L$. The intersections of those lines with $M$ establishes a bijection.

Almost a duplicate of
[Number of points on a line in a finite projective plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1627894/number-of-points-on-a-line-in-a-finite-projective-plane)

Comment: Why must there exist a point $P$ that's on neither line?

Comment: John Hughes seems to use his "Axiom D" in his proof when he says "Let $D$ be a point of $D$ [sic] distinct from $B$ and $C$".

Comment: I still think this answer is incomplete; it seems to be assuming Axiom 4, which is what we're trying to prove.

Comment: I see no use of Axiom 4 in my argument. We may just have to disagree about it's correctness.

Comment: @xFioraMstr18 Re:"Why must there exist a point $P$ that's on neither line?" This result is proved via contradiction as Lemma 2.1 in Albert & Sandler's _An Introduction to Finite Projective Planes_ (1968, Holt, Rinehart and Winston, p. 16).